# How to print binary from an integer

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    int testNums[] = {3, 0x12, 0xFF, -3};
    int testBits[] = {9, 7, 12, 15};
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(testNums) / sizeof(testNums[0]); i++)
        printBin(testNums[i], testBits[i]);
}

void printBin(int num, int bits)
{
    int pow;
    int mask = 1 << bits - 1;

    for(pow=0; pow<bits; pow++)
    {
        if(mask & num)
            printf("1");
        else
            printf("0");
        num<<1;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

It doesn't print out the correct binary number, but has the right amount of bits, and advice on how I can fix this?

Comment: "It doesn't print out the correct binary number, but has the right amount of bits" Perhaps, giving the expected result and the actual result you got would be helpful to evaluate your code and pin point possible mistakes without the pain of re-duplicating/imagining it.

Comment: 000000000                                                                                                                    0000000                                                                                                                000000000000                                                                                                         111111111111111 it outputs these binary values vertically

Comment: Because of your `printf("\n");`? You should edit your question (don't put in the comment)

Comment: Look at num<<1. That's not quite right.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here, in `printBin`:

```
num<<1;
```

This statement does nothing.  What you want is:

```
num<<=1;
```

For clarity, you should also use parenthesis here:

```
int mask = 1 << (bits - 1);
```

And you should move `printBin` above `main` so the definition is visible at the time the function is called.

Finally, `main` should always return `int`.

Comment: @byongsun  `num<<1` does not change the value of `num`,  it just takes the value of `num`, shifts that value left once and throws the result away.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues in your code:

1. You need a prototype for `printBin()`.
2. Use `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char** argv)` instead of `void main()`.
3. `num<<1;` is an expression that has no side effects. Perhaps you are able infer this from compiler's warning. Write `num<<=1;` to make a difference.
4. Only a suggestion: Why not replace the if statement with `printf("%d", !!(mask & num));`?

Here is the fixed code that compiles without warnings using clang:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void printBin(int num, int bits);

int main(void)
{
        int testNums[] = {3, 0x12, 0xFF, -3};
        int testBits[] = {9, 7, 12, 15};
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < sizeof testNums / sizeof testNums[0]; i++)
                printBin(testNums[i], testBits[i]);
        return 0;
}

void printBin(int num, int bits)
{
        int pow;
        int mask = 1 << (bits - 1);

        for(pow=0; pow<bits; pow++)
        {
                printf("%d", mask & num);
                num <<= 1;
        }
        putchar('\n');
}
```

Output:

```
000000011
0010010
000011111111
111111111111101
```

Answer (score 0):

Although your approach is conventional and @dbush's answer is appropriate, I would like like to mention another approach. You may know this and it **doesn't** handle the negative values very well but in this approach, you can **convert number of any base into other very easily**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define RESOLUTION 128

void compute(int number, int base, char* placeHolder){
    int k = 0;
    int i, j;
    char temp;
    while(number){
        placeHolder[k++] = "0123456789ABCDEF"[number % base];
        number /= base;
    }
    if (k != 0) {
      placeHolder[k] = '\0';
      for(i = 0, j = strlen(placeHolder) - 1; i < j; i++, j--){
        temp = placeHolder[i];
        placeHolder[i] = placeHolder[j];
        placeHolder[j] = temp;
      }
    }else{
        placeHolder[0] = '0';
        placeHolder[1] = '\0';
    }
}


int main(void) {
    char bin[RESOLUTION];
    compute(0xFF, 10, bin);
    printf("%s\n", bin);
    return 0;
}
```

Change the `RESOLUTION` value at you will.

**More specific to binary, you can print binary of any datatype like this**

```
void printBits(size_t const size, void const * const ptr)
{
    unsigned char *b = (unsigned char*) ptr;
    unsigned char byte;
    int i, j;

    for (i=size-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        for (j=7;j>=0;j--)
        {
            byte = b[i] & (1<<j);
            byte >>= j;
            printf("%u", byte);
        }
    }
    puts("");
}


int main()
{
        int i = 23;
        uint ui = UINT_MAX;
        float f = 23.45f;
        printBits(sizeof(i), &i);
        printBits(sizeof(ui), &ui);
        printBits(sizeof(f), &f);
        return 0;
}
```